# How to use inner SELECT inside INSERT statement

Tags: sql-server

I have this problem. I have a `Currency` table which looks like this :

```
Id|IntKey|Text
1  10     USD
2  20     EUR
```

A have another table - `Accounts` where I have Foreign Key `CurrencyId`. The problem is that when I collect the information for an account the Currency comes to me as string value or the `Text` column value in my database. However I want to use `IntKey` to match the `CurrencyId` so what I want is in my `INSERT` query to provide the `IntKey` based on the string valued.

The easy way that I can implement myself is first take the value I need is just to perfrom a separate select like

`SELECT IntKey FROM Currency WHERE Text = @param`

then execute it, take the value and use it in my `INSERT` however I would liek to combine it to one query (if possible) I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[Accounts] VALUES
(@IBAN, SELECT IntKey FROM [dbo].[Currency] WHERE Text = @param, ...)
```

and then

`SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertNewAccount, connection);`
`command.ExecuteScalar();`

But this doesn't work. Is this possible and how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with parenthesises?

```
INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[Accounts] VALUES
(
   @IBAN, 
   (SELECT IntKey FROM [dbo].[Currency] WHERE Text = @param), 
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close to it.

```
INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[Accounts] 
SELECT @IBAN, @otherValue, @anotherValue, IntKey FROM [dbo].[Currency] 
WHERE Text = @param
```

No need for `VALUES`, and `SELECT` has to be around all columns and variables.

Comment: I get this query `"INSERT INTO [DB].[dbo].[Accounts] SELECT @IBAN,IntKey FROM [dbo].[Currency] WHERE Text = @param, ..` which when I try to execute gives me an erro "Invalid syntax near ','`

Comment: Sorry, I missread your question. If you want to insert other columns, they need to be in the `SELECT` statement, as `@variables` or columns from the query.